# TFS discard not working on rollback changesets

Tags: merge, rollback, tfs-sdk

We have a situation where work had been done in the trunk of our system but was then pulled for our next release. We created a branch with the changes still in the trunk and then rolled back the changes in the trunk only.

What that's left us with though is that whenever we want to update the branch with recent work from working, it tries to merge the rollback changesets which we don't want.

I've tried using the /discard command from the TFS command prompt but keep getting "There are no changes to merge". Here is my syntax below:

```
D:\Projects\Big Project\Trunk>tf merge /discard /version:C28350~C28350 /recursive "D:\Projects\Big Project\Trunk" "D:\Projects\Big Project\Branch"
```

I even tried switching around the source and the destination to no avail :)

The changeset appears in the list of candidate changesets for the potential merge from trunk to branch. There have been a few checkins to the working branch since the initial branching but none to the branch.

Does anyone have experience with the discard command and why it may not be working here??

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: I added the /baseless flag to the above command and this gave me the results I was looking for in terms of discarding the right files from the changeset. Not sure if this is a final solution though. Maybe someone who understands this flag a bit better can explain what this means/implies??

Answer (score 1):

Reading through `tf rollback` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380776.aspx) the option `/keepmergehistory` is there exactly for these scenarios. (Please see the relevant example at the end of the help doco).

Your scenario is different, here are the steps I would follow (command prompt omitted):

```
tf merge /version:C28350~C28350 /recursive "D:\Projects\Big Project\Trunk" "D:\Projects\Big Project\Branch"

tf checkin /recursive "D:\Projects\Big Project\Branch"

tf rollback /version:XXXX /recursive /keepmergehistory "D:\Projects\Big Project\Branch"
```

Comments about the steps:

1. Without the `/discard` option
2. Check that change in, even though you're not interested in it; note the changeset number for the XXXX in the next step...
3. Now rollback that particular change, and use `/keepmergehistory` so that TFS won't ever ask you again about merging this change.

Alternatively, you should be able to rollback the rollback in the trunk, then re-apply with this flag - but I'm not sure the `/keepmergehistory` works both ways.. here goes: (not sure I put the parameters there correctly...)

```
tf rollback /version:C28350 /toversion:C28349 /recursive "D:\Projects\Big Project\Trunk"

tf rollback /version:XXXX /toversion:XXXX-1 /recursive /keepmergehistory "D:\Projects\Big Project\Trunk"
```

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by telling TFS to ignore history while performing the merge.  In other words, it can be done using a baseless merge:

> `D:\Projects\Big Project\Trunk>tf merge /discard /version:C28350~C28350 /recursive /baseless "D:\Projects\Big Project\Trunk" "D:\Projects\Big Project\Branch"`